# hide woo commerce dashboard status and reports from woo commerce from specific users but display to other users

Tags: users, woocommerce-offtopic, dashboard, post-status

I am trying to display Woocommerce Dashboard Status where sales reports are displayed only to following users.

user1 > shop manager
and administrator

Trying to hide Dashboard Status and Report and Setting section in Woocommerce from User2 only.

Is there a specific code that i can target specific user and hide these menus and dashboard display.

I have managed to hide following menu with the these codes.

```
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_menus' );
function remove_menus(){
    $role = get_role( 'shop_manager' );
    remove_menu_page( 'vc-welcome' );//removes visual compose

    if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {

        //remove_menu_page( 'woocommerce' ); // WooCommerce admin menu slug
        remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'themes.php' );
        remove_menu_page( 'mpcth-options-framework' );
        remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' );
        remove_menu_page( 'mpc_badge' );
        remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' );
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=essential_grid' );
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=mpc_badge' );
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=mpc_portfolio' );
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=mpc_grid');



    }}
```

Maybe I can some how use this $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

get current user ID and if the current user ID is equal to the user ID of user2 then remove_submenu_page or remove_menu_page to remove woo commerce submenu like Settings and reports for that particular user only. Hope you are still with me :D

Please help thank you or please let me know here i can look up.

Answer (score 0):

For the dashboard case.

```
if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {

function remove_dashboard_widgets() {

        // remove WooCommerce Dashboard Status
        remove_meta_box( 'woocommerce_dashboard_status', 'dashboard', 'normal');    
    }
    add_action('wp_user_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets', 20);
    add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets', 20);
}
```